# Перебрать массив, что бы Страны содержали в себе массив городов. Нужно сделать с помощью foreach или другого цикла

Tags: php, массивы

```
Дан список городов и их стран, хранящийся в следующей структуре:

[
[
    'country' => 'Россия',
    'city' =>    'Москва',
],
[
    'country' => 'Беларусь',
    'city' =>    'Минск',
],
[
    'country' => 'Россия',
    'city' =>    'Питер',
],
[
    'country' => 'Россия',
    'city' =>    'Владивосток',
],
[
    'country' => 'Украина',
    'city' =>    'Львов',
],
[
    'country' => 'Беларусь',
    'city' =>    'Могилев',
],
[
    'country' => 'Украина',
    'city' =>    'Киев',
],
```

]

Напишите код, которой переделает структуру данных вот в такую:

[
'Россия'=> [
'Москва', 'Питер', 'Владивосток',
],
'Беларусь'=> [
'Минск', 'Могилев'
],
'Украина'=> [
'Киев', 'Львов'
],
]
Пробовал как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо было монитор зафотать.